# App Engine Cron Tasks fail with no entries in log. How to debug?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I recently updated my cron.yaml file and now my cron tasks fail with no entries in the logs.

It is acting like the java servlet at the url is not being run.

I can paste the url into a browser and the servlet runs fine.

My cron.yaml file:

```
cron:

  - description: Daily revenues report
    url: /revenues
    schedule: every day 07:35
    timezone: America/Denver
```

Using below deploycron.sh

```
PROJECT_ID='my-project-id'
gcloud config set project ${PROJECT_ID}
gcloud info
gcloud app deploy cron.yaml
```

Is there an error in my .yaml?

Is there a special task queue set up required?

Is some other configuration or permissions piece missing?

It was running fine last week. I have tried deleting and starting over to no avail.

https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler?project=project-id

Shows the job. Result column 'Failed'.

Logs 'View' link shows:

protoPayload.taskName="01661931846119241031" protoPayload.taskQueueName="__cron"

with no log entries.

Is __cron not automatic?

I am at a loss.

App Engine Standard. Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the latest update of GCloud locally and re-running the deploy cron script. The cron jobs now run as before. 02/02/2021.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks, Bruce!

Answer (score 0):

'Failed' means that the endpoint `/revenues` is not returning a success http status code.

> Logs 'View' link shows: protoPayload.taskName="01661931846119241031" protoPayload.taskQueueName="__cron" with no log entries

Maybe don't use the premade filter, and just try filtering for `/revenues` or viewing all the logs at 07:35 am (when it was supposed to have run)

> Is there an error in my .yaml?

if there was then `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml` would fail

> Is there a special task queue set up required?

you shouldn't need to do anything, i didn't

> I can paste the url into a browser and the servlet runs fine.

When you paste the url into the browser, is there any redirecting (like from `/revenues` to `/revenues/`) or anything that your browser is handling for you. Maybe `/revenues` is expecting there to be cookies present now.

What are there any special `app.yaml` or `dispatch.yaml` rules that `/revenues` would be hitting?

Is `/revenues` being handled by a service other than the `default` service?

Comment: I have checked everything you have suggested and cannot find an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: CRON tasks fail without any logs.
The root cause was that the *IP address of App Engine was blocked* by the App Engine Firewall. Thus I had to update the allow-list, as described here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#validating_cron_requests

Answer (score -1):

I started having the same problem a few days ago on my existing CRON schedules. I've tried everything including tearing my code down to the bare minimum and creating a new GAE project with the Hello World quick start. It still fails. Nothing useful in the logs and the UI just says 'Failed'. I'm pulling my hair out.

Sorry I don't have an answer to contribute but your post makes me think it's on Google's side. I know they're moving CRON jobs to Cloud Scheduler->App Engine Cron Jobs. My gut tells me it's a permissions issue related to this move and IAM. I'm really at a loss.

Comment: Thank you for posting. I think you are right. I think Google introduced a bug somewhere along the way. Please post once this is resolved.